# Does GitLab not support sequential pipelines?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have been looking for a way to prevent multiple pipelines for multiple commits and/or branches from running in parallel. Due to external resource usage, it is not feasible for us to run pipelines in parallel, but I could not find a way to specify a restriction to sequential running.

This seems to fundamental a feature to not be supported out of the box, it seems, so am I missing something ?

Setting up a dedicated runner each for 100+ projects does also not seem like a sensible 'solution'.

Answer (score 0):

If you run a dedicated GitLab runner, you can control the number of jobs running in parallel by setting the key `concurrent` in the [global section](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#the-global-section) of the configuration file `/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml`:

```
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 10
```

Comment: In addition to the above, you can also use the "Auto Cancel Redundant Pipelines" in your CI/CD config of a project to cancel a pipeline if a second pipeline on the same branch is created. For this to work, your jobs will need to have `interruptable:true` set on them.

Comment: It seems like this way, I would be restricted to either set up 100+ runners, one for each project, or have ALL jobs run sequentially, independent of project, right ?

Comment: You can `tag` the runners as say light (concurrent > 1) and heavy (concurrent set to 1) groups and assign jobs that can run in parallel to the first type and the other to the second one. And even have some runners dedicated to some special projects. I do not know other possible setups.

Comment: That way I am limiting all projects with pipelines that can not run in parallel to run in sequence against each other, which is also extremely undesirable. It appears that really the only solution is to actually set up ~100 individual runners, which are limited to one instance each.